# Using RequireJS with TypeScript and Retaining Intellisense

Tags: typescript

I've gotten used to using TypeScript in Visual Studio, but only to write plain JavaScript (I realize the power of TypeScript's custom syntax, but prefer to hedge my bets and maintain my JS proficiency!). My question has to do with utilizing RequireJS in this environment. For example:

```
require(["jquery", "app/utils.js"], function ($, utils) {
    console.log(utils.doSomething());
});
```

...and my utils.js looks like this:

```
define([], function () {
    var doSomething = function () {
        return "ok";
    };
    return {
        doSomething: doSomething
    };
});
```

This is what I write in TypeScript. In my perfect little world, I would love to be able to utilize intellisense to see the properties of `utils` in this case (so when I'm typing `utils`, I see `utils.doSomething` as an option).

I'm guessing the answer is "can't do it" and I have to use the import/export TS syntax, but thought I would check anyway!

Comment: Why not just write TypeScript? If you change your mind later, just compile your code once, delete the .ts files, and start editing the generated .js files.

Comment: if you don't want to use typescript, i suggest you use webstorm, as that gives syntax .intelisence as you wish.  you might also be able to use resharper if you use visual studio, but not too sure.

Comment: Great responses, thanks! Looks like it's time to bite the bullet and go all-in on TypeScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript defaults to CommonJS-style of module exports (i.e. assigning members to the `exports` variable). This is the way to do it in TypeScript with Intellisense support for Visual Studio:

```
define([], function () {
    var doSomething = function () {
        return "ok";
    };
    var r = {
        doSomething: doSomething
    };
    export = r;
});
```

However, if you want to stay 100% in JavaScript, you'll need to write a type definition file `app.d.ts` for your module to provide the type information:

```
declare module "app/utils"
{
        function doSomething(): string;
}
```

In your app:

```
///<reference path="app.d.ts" />

require(["jquery", "app/utils"], function ($, utils) {
    console.log(utils.doSomething());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If *utils.js* is indeed a javascript file then TypeScript isn't going to give you intellisense  for free. You need to write declarations for javascript files:

So you can create a **utils.d.ts** file which looks like this:

```
module utils {
    doSomething():string;
}
```

This will enable you to add this to your original file:

```
///<reference src="app/utils.d.ts" />
```

And now you should get intellisense.

This however feels very wrong, as why would you write definition files for **new** javascript code you are writing yourself, this is almost like writing the code twice. 
If you can just bite the bullet and go with typescript, you should. Hedging your bets in going to give you more work (of course if we are talking existing code then the definition/declaration files are probably worth it as you won't have to port existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the interface inline :

```
require(["jquery", "app/utils.js"], function ($, utils : { doSomething:()=>string; } ) {
    console.log(utils.doSomething());
});
```

Or outside

```
interface IUtils {
    doSomething:()=>string; 
}
require(["jquery", "app/utils.js"], function ($, utils : IUtils ) {
    console.log(utils.doSomething());
});
```